# How to automatically call PFQuery when scrolling down in a UICollectionView

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, parse-platform, pfquery

I have an `UICollectionView` in which each cell contains a `PFObject`. As there are potentially hundreds of these objects for each `UICollectionView`, I don't want to query all the objects at once, and instead only call a limited amount, and then automatically call for more as the user scroll towards the end (somewhat like endless scrolling that many web apps use).

Would `PFQuery` support these type of calls, and if so how would I be able to call continuously and automatically?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps something like this to get you on the right track:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {

    float scrollViewHeight = scrollView.frame.size.height;
    float scrollContentSizeHeight = scrollView.contentSize.height;

    else if (scrollView.contentOffset.y <= 0) {
        // then we are at the top
    }
    else if (scrollView.contentOffset.y + scrollViewHeight >= scrollContentSizeHeight) {
        // then we are at the bottom - query new results


    }

}
```

I don't think you'd have to add anything for it to call as long as your controller is already your collectionView's delegate.